# Dynamically increasing radio button validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some radio buttons that dynamically increase based on data. What I want is to check if all radio button are selected or not. If they're not, I want to show an error message on that particular row as I am using form substitution to send data to ajax.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // radio buttons
   $('#mySpan4').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax2.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(), // reads the data ...
       success: function(data) {
         alert("data Updated Successfully");
         window.location = 'login.html';
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mySpan4">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name : abc
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[0]" value="Mother">Mother
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[0]" value="Father">Father
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name : def
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[1]" value="Mother">Mother
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[1]" value="Father">Father
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name : ghi
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[2]" value="Mother">Mother
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[2]" value="Father">Father
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `:checked`

```
var all = $('input[type=radio][name^=game]').length;
var chk = $('input[type=radio][name^=game]:checked').length;
var exp = all / 2;// in a group two radios each, any one will be selected
if(chk === exp) {
  //all checked
} else {
  // some goup is not checked
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // radio buttons
  $('#mySpan4').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var all = $('input[type=radio][name^=game]').length;
    var chk = $('input[type=radio][name^=game]:checked').length;
    var exp = all / 2; // in a group two radios each, any one will be selected
    if (chk !== exp) {
      alert('Error, select all !');
      return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax2.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(), // reads the data ...
      success: function(data) {
        alert("data Updated Successfully");
        window.location = 'login.html';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mySpan4">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name : abc
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[0]" value="Mother">Mother
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[0]" value="Father">Father
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name : def
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[1]" value="Mother">Mother
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[1]" value="Father">Father
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name : ghi
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[2]" value="Mother">Mother
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="game[2]" value="Father">Father
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: i need that to send that to data base if all selected as mentioned above java script on form submitting i mean on submit button click can u plz Help me on that was expecting the same as u have provided.

Comment: Got it Was unable to send Form data

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the radio buttons and check weather its checked.

```
$(input[type="radio"]).each(function(val, i){
   if($(val.is('checked'))){
     //all checked
  }else{
    //Not all checked
  }

})
```

Comment: Can you please modify ur ans With My javascript